# Create d3 linear color legend using d3 colors

Tags: d3.js, colors, legend, linear-gradients

I want to create color legend using linear gradient > https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/6eb89487fc99ad016723b901cbd57fde . But how can I pass my d3 colors here because its in the form like d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis).domain([0,1]). In linear gradient the colors are passed as below :

```
var data = [{"color":"#000004","value":0},{"color":"#02020c","value":5}]

linearGradient.selectAll("stop")
.data(data)
.enter().append("stop")
.attr("offset", d => ((d.value - extent[0]) / (extent[1] - extent[0]) * 100) + "%")
.attr("stop-color", d => d.color);
```

Note: My dataset is like below:

```
export const colorScales: Record<string, (num: number) => string> = {
Rainbow: d3.interpolateHslLong("red", "blue"),
Spectral: d3.interpolateSpectral,
RdYlBu: d3.interpolateRdYlBu,
RdYlGn: d3.interpolateRdYlGn,
RdBu: d3.interpolateRdBu,
PiYG: d3.interpolatePiYG,
Warm: d3.interpolateWarm,
Cool: d3.interpolateCool,
Viridis: d3.interpolateViridis,
Inferno: d3.interpolateInferno,
Magma: d3.interpolateMagma,
Plasma: d3.interpolatePlasma,
CubeHelix: d3.interpolateCubehelixDefault,
YlOrRd: d3.interpolateYlOrRd,
Blues: d3.interpolateBlues,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using `d3.interpolateSpectral`. You can create your data with `d3.range` and `map`:

```
// create an array of steps based on the color scale
var data = d3.range(10).map(d=> ({color:d3.interpolateSpectral(d/10), value:d}))
// get the array's min and max value
var extent = d3.extent(data, d => d.value); 

linearGradient.selectAll("stop")
.data(data)
.enter().append("stop")
.attr("offset", d => ((d.value - extent[0]) / (extent[1] - extent[0]) * 100) + "%")
.attr("stop-color", d => d.color);
```

Technically you could do it with colors from those categorical schemes, but it doesn't make much sense to me.

```
 // d3.schemeCategory10 is just an array of color
 // use map to add some values (index in this case)

var data = d3.schemeCategory10.map((d,i) => ({color:d, value:i}))

linearGradient.selectAll("stop")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("stop")
    .attr("offset", d => d.value/9 * 100) + "%") // index/length
    .attr("stop-color", d => d.color);
```

Comment: I am creating color selector for both discrete and continuous data. Can I use linear gradient to create discrete legend as well ? I mean how can I use ex: d3.schemeCategory10 (discrete color scale) to create discrete legend.

Comment: I don't totally understand why, but yes I think you could. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure though if I have my own colors array with r g b values ,then to create separate legend for discrete and continuous data or I can take single legend and show it as continuous and discrete way by passing data .

Comment: I think that relates to what makes sense for your data. Its hard for me to imagine a case where schemeCategory10 makes sense to be used for a continuous scale.  You won't see the colors in your gradient reflected in the chart.

Comment: The code above mentioned by you uses discrete color to show continuous legend/scale. But I want to use discrete color (ex: d3.schemeCategory10) to show discrete legend (using same linear gradient code). Is it possible to use same linear gradient code to show both discrete and continuous legend because at a time I will be showing only one legend (either discrete or continuous) based on some condition. So my goal is to use single legend code and pass data accordingly. But I am not sure how can I pass ex:d3.schemeCategory10 to show discrete legend.

Comment: What do you expect a  legend with a gradient to look like? `schemeCategory10` is for categorical data. The colors don't have an obvious "direction". Their order in a gradient would just be arbitrary. Plus the gradient, by design, will mostly display colors (those in between two categories) that won't ever appear on your visualization.

Comment: I wanted my legend to look something like this https://nick3499.medium.com/d3-scaleordinal-d3-schemecategory10-categorical-ordinal-scale-cab259c4d1e5 using same linear gradient code written for continuous data. Is that possible ?

Comment: No, because that isn't a gradient. You just wouldn't use a gradient fill there.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will create other legend for discrete data.

Comment: I have an requirement for logarithm Sampling. Can I use same legend created using linear gradient for logarithm sampling/interpolation ?